# How to identify page not found by path and rediect to landing page by path

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a static website. I would like to make the page not found show and then redirect after 10 seconds.

But it has 3 languages with 3 paths. So how can I make the redirection page  get the path and redirect to path landing page?

E.g.

- www.abc.com/langA/shxbdjdbsj.html -> go to 404 not found page (10 second redirect to) -> www.abc.com/langA/index.html
- www.abc.com/langB/isjjjsjdjdbsj.html -> go to 404 not found page (10 second redirect to) -> www.abc.com/langB/index.html
- www.abc.com/langC/odbdbcjsnjs.html -> go to 404 not found page (10 second redirect to) -> www.abc.com/langC/index.html

I know how to set a 404 page in apache. I know how to perform an auto redirect in html. I know how to redirect by user browser detection.

But I don't know how to implement the language specific redirections detailed above.

Answer (score 0):

This what you can try is .htaccess, there is a specific rule that when browser language is set to en or any other language you can redirect to page which you want.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*site.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/fr/ [L,R=301]
```

As you can see this is a example if the language is set to fr - French it will redirect to /fr/ subfolder on the same website. You can change it to your own use.